# Multiple H264 video windows with gstream 1.0: Possible?

Tags: streaming-video

I managed to install gstreamer 1.0, and obtain a H264 streaming form HD surveillance camera, Axis 1054.
I had to use gstreamer 1.0, as omx player seem to lock after a second of camera streaming or rtsp://.....

I would like to:

- a) in one monitor, cyclically and AUTOMATICALY switch from one camera
  stream, to a different camera .
- b) in a second monitor, have a    “mosaic” of four camera displayed
  SIMULTANEOUSLY, coming from four    different surveillance camera.

PROBLEMS:

- a) Switching video: starting gstreamer from command line, is not
  retuning focus to the consolle; alias it seems not possible to send
  command to the running gstreamer instance to change stream source; any other method ?
- b) Multiple windows: gstreamer instance seems to hold exclusive use
  of the screen, so I cannon understand if I can position and size four
  different output windows SIMULTANEOUSLY. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly how you got the stream and what protocols you used but you can use

[crtmp-server](http://www.rtmpd.com/)  - I am not sure if you can compile it on the Pi but it runs well on external Ubuntu/Debian servers.

[nginx rtmp-module](http://pkula.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/live-video-stream-from-raspberry-pi.html)  - This is a really great module. It has a ton of features that I am sure you could use for your CCTV like operations. It does require compiling but it is worth the effort and it runs pretty well on the Pi.

Either way then you can use a web page and create your own layouts, or even software that can request rtmp, rtmsp or whatever. With the Raspberry Pi camera I managed to get the live stream about 0.4ms lag. I think that is the fastest at the moment using 1080p@25fps on the Raspbery pushed to external servers and also serving locally.

It is wrapped in a flash container but the stream is pure h264 - You can adjsut it any way you like.